# Spring - PropertiesPlaceholderConfigurer not finding properties file

Tags: java, spring

Not sure what could be wrong.

I had an app that worked all along with this

```
<context:property-placeholder location="classpath:my.properties"/>
```

No problems finding the properties file and hooking things up.

Now, I needed to encrypt some fields in the properties file. So I ended up writing the custom PropertiesPlaceholderConfigurer and tried to wire it up like this

```
<bean class="com.mycompany.myapp.PropertiesPlaceholderConfigurer">
        <property name="location" value="classpath:my.propeties"/>
    </bean>
```

With this configuration, Spring complains that it cannot find the properties file.

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [my.propeties] cannot be opened because it does not exist
```

What in addition should be done?

The custom placeholder configurer

```
package com.mycompany.myapp;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer;
import org.springframework.util.ObjectUtils;

import java.util.Enumeration;
import java.util.Properties;


public class PropertiesPlaceholderConfigurer extends PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer{

    @Override
    protected void convertProperties(Properties props) {
        Enumeration<?> propertyNames = props.propertyNames();
        while (propertyNames.hasMoreElements()) {
            String propertyName = (String) propertyNames.nextElement();
            String propertyValue = props.getProperty(propertyName);
            if(propertyName.endsWith("encrypted")){
                System.out.println("Decrypting the property " + propertyName);
                String convertedValue = decrypt(propertyValue);
                System.out.println("Decrypted the property value to " + convertedValue);
                if (!ObjectUtils.nullSafeEquals(propertyValue, convertedValue)) {
                    props.setProperty(propertyName, convertedValue);
                }
            }

        }
    }

}
```

---

Update:

Forget my custom placeholder configurer, even the spring provided one has trouble if I replace  with this

```
 <bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
     <property name="location" value="classpath:my.propeties"/>
 </bean>
```

What is context:property-placholder doing that the bean definition can't?

---

Full stack trace

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
    at org.springframework.test.context.CacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(CacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:99)
    at org.springframework.test.context.DefaultTestContext.getApplicationContext(DefaultTestContext.java:101)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.injectDependencies(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:109)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:75)
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:319)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.createTest(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:212)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner$1.runReflectiveCall(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:289)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.methodBlock(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:291)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:232)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:89)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:238)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:63)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:236)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:53)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:229)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:309)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:175)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.execute(JUnit4Provider.java:264)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.executeTestSet(JUnit4Provider.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.invoke(JUnit4Provider.java:124)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.invokeProviderInSameClassLoader(ForkedBooter.java:200)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.runSuitesInProcess(ForkedBooter.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:103)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanInitializationException: Could not load properties; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [my.propeties] cannot be opened because it does not exist
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyResourceConfigurer.postProcessBeanFactory(PropertyResourceConfigurer.java:89)
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:265)
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:162)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:609)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:464)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractGenericContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractGenericContextLoader.java:121)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractGenericContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractGenericContextLoader.java:60)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.delegateLoading(AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.java:100)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.java:250)
    at org.springframework.test.context.CacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContextInternal(CacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:64)
    at org.springframework.test.context.CacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(CacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:91)
    at org.springframework.test.context.DefaultTestContext.getApplicationContext(DefaultTestContext.java:101)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.injectDependencies(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:109)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:75)
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:319)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.createTest(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:212)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner$1.runReflectiveCall(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:289)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.methodBlock(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:291)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:232)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:89)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:238)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:63)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:236)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:53)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:229)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:309)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:175)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.execute(JUnit4Provider.java:264)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.executeTestSet(JUnit4Provider.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.invoke(JUnit4Provider.java:124)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.invokeProviderInSameClassLoader(ForkedBooter.java:200)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.runSuitesInProcess(ForkedBooter.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:103)
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [my.propeties] cannot be opened because it does not exist
    at org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource.getInputStream(ClassPathResource.java:158)
    at org.springframework.core.io.support.EncodedResource.getInputStream(EncodedResource.java:143)
    at org.springframework.core.io.support.PropertiesLoaderUtils.fillProperties(PropertiesLoaderUtils.java:98)
    at org.springframework.core.io.support.PropertiesLoaderSupport.loadProperties(PropertiesLoaderSupport.java:175)
    at org.springframework.core.io.support.PropertiesLoaderSupport.mergeProperties(PropertiesLoaderSupport.java:156)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyResourceConfigurer.postProcessBeanFactory(PropertyResourceConfigurer.java:80)
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:265)
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:162)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:609)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:464)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractGenericContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractGenericContextLoader.java:121)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractGenericContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractGenericContextLoader.java:60)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.delegateLoading(AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.java:100)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.java:250)
    at org.springframework.test.context.CacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContextInternal(CacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:64)
    at org.springframework.test.context.CacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(CacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:91)
    at org.springframework.test.context.DefaultTestContext.getApplicationContext(DefaultTestContext.java:101)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.injectDependencies(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:109)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:75)
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:319)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.createTest(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:212)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner$1.runReflectiveCall(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:289)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.methodBlock(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:291)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:232)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:89)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:238)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:63)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:236)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:53)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:229)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:309)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:175)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.execute(JUnit4Provider.java:264)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.executeTestSet(JUnit4Provider.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.invoke(JUnit4Provider.java:124)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.invokeProviderInSameClassLoader(ForkedBooter.java:200)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.runSuitesInProcess(ForkedBooter.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:103)
```

Comment: Please post the full stack trace and any relevant implementation details of your `PropertiesPlaceholderConfigurer`.

Comment: First, are you sure your resource is on the classpath at runtime and is at the location you specified, ie. root?

Comment: Again...the only change needed to make this run is to replace my custom placholder configurer with this - <context:property-placeholder location="classpath:my.properties"/> in the spring configuration file. So I'd be very surprised if this configuration change will suddenly cause the classpath to change

Comment: What Spring version are you on?

Comment: Spring version - 4.0.2

Comment: The only thing close to what you are experiencing is the `<context:property-placeholder>` having an attribute of `ignore-resource-not-found` set to `true`. If that's not the case, I really can't see why it wouldn't work.

Comment: I did not have ignore-resource-not-found on the context tag. Strange. Don't have very many ideas on what could be going on.

Comment: I can't reproduce this.

Comment: I am not sure why, but I just upgraded to 4.0.5 and the problem is gone. So its definitely got something to do with 4.0.2

Comment: While you are at it, can you post a minimal context configuration which will cause this? With minimal beans and other elements.

Answer (score 1):

The problem seems to be with Spring 4.0.2 version. I upgraded to 4.0.5 and the problem disappeared.

Answer (score 0):

This works:

In your Spring config:

```
<bean id="config" class="com.domain.Configuration">
    <constructor-arg value="me.properties"/>
</bean>
```

And your custom PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer:

```
public class Configuration extends PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer {
    private Properties props = new Properties();

    public Configuration(String fileName) {
        InputStream in = this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("/" + fileName);
        props.load(new InputStreamReader(in));
        //Set the props on the superclass
        super.setProperties(props);
    }

    @Override
    protected String resolvePlaceholder(String placeholder, Properties props) {
        //See if we need to do any decryption
        if (placeholder.endsWith("password")) {
            return getPassword(placeholder);
        }
        return super.resolvePlaceholder(placeholder, props);
    }
```

I've edited the code above to remove a lot of the boiler plate around it so you may need to make some slight adjustments.

Answer (score 0):

I can't reproduce this.

The only difference between your `<bean>` declaration and `<context:property-placeholder>` is that the latter registers a `PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer` rather than a `PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer`. It does this in `PropertyPlaceholderBeanDefinitionParser` which handles parsing the `property-placeholder` XML element.

Both `PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer` and `PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer` are subclasses of `PropertiesLoaderSupport` which has the `location` property/field. Both handle converting the `String` value to a `Resource` object the same way. Both delegate to that `Resource` object to `getInputStream()` and retrieve the underlying properties.

There is nothing in what you've shown us that would cause the behavior you are experiencing.

A different `ClassLoader` might explain this. A different classpath configuration might explain this. A different configuration of the beans might explain this.

Comment: I will see if I can push a pared down version of the project to github. It will take sometime though to strip it down so I don't intrude on IP rights of the company.

Comment: @sat Thanks for taking the time to do this. I'm a really curious now.

Answer (score 0):

Have you used `base package to scan` ?

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.java.spring" />
```

then try to load your `.properties` file.

If possible then do like this :

```
<context:property-placeholder location="classpath:*.properties" />
```

if it's working then try to add `specific name` instead of `*`.

Still got problem then post me.

Comment: Yes. I do have the <context:component-scan base-package="..."/>. The classpath with *.properties wasn't working. I will try to see if I can push a stripped down version with the problem to github. I can't push the project as it is for obvious reasons